# Is it possible to run Chrome from a flash drive?

Tags: google-chrome

I want to be able to run an instance of Google Chrome from a folder in a flash drive, and have it run with cookies on the flash drive.  Any new cookies should be saved in the same folder.

Basically, I want a standalone isolated version of Chrome, independent of any other installation of Chrome which may or may not exist on the computer I am using.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @fixer1234 Windows

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to run [an instance of Tor on a USB](https://www.maketecheasier.com/install-tor-browser-usb-drive/), additionally some software allow a user to set the installer to install that software on a USB. There is a website called [portableapps.com](https://portableapps.com) that allow a user to install certain software onto a USB, Dropbox, Google Drive, and an external hard drive via a Windows machine (Macs and various flavors of Linux are also compatible via [Wine](https://www.winehq.org) and [CrossOver](https://www.codeweavers.com/products/)).

Comment: Chromium on portableapps hasn’t been updated in 3 years